# Devise: Missing partial when accessing edit registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Im trying to render a collection of user inboxes:

```
<%= render current_user.my_inbox %>
```

It works fine with different views/controller except when i attempt to access the devise edit registration.

> Missing partial devise/inboxes/_inbox

I notice that Devise is not looking at the right path. how do i tell devise that my inbox partial is located at `inboxes/_inbox` not `devise/inboxes/_inbox`

any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Assign the partial's name manually and pass along the data.

```
<%= render partial: "inboxes/inbox", collection: current_user.my_inbox %>
```

- More info in the [Rails Partial Docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials) *(specifically passing variables to a given partial)*

Comment: @mrvncaragay You'll need to be more specific than that